# su executable not found sudo requires su - termux

Tags: linux, sudo, termux, termux-linux

I'm finding it difficult to write a sudo command even after installing termux-sudo
[image]

Comment: Why not just install `su`?

Comment: How do i install it @BarryCarter

Answer (score 0):

Some questions (I don't have the reputation to comment.):

- Did you root your phone?
- ternux-sudo looks wrong to me. Should it be termux-sudo?

I rooted my old phone, and then I could just type su to get a root shell. I suspect you did not root your phone.

Answer (score 0):

I made a guide once to get rid of the sudo problems with termux.
Take look at this:

https://www.reddit.com/r/termux/comments/ewy35k/i_made_my_termux_go_root_for_real/

Answer (score 0):

Is your phone rooted, if yes just type tsu
And if you're not root, you can install fake-sudo in my github.
Just add my repository and install by typing: apt install fake-sudo

https://github.com/ArieSR91/user91-repo/